# BiqQuery find decimal point in String and remove everything are decimal (including Decimal)

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery and need help finishing my query.

We have a dataset of Order numbers that have a few issues (This is what I want to achieve)

| OrderNo | Outcome |
| --- | --- |
| 18446 | 18446 |
| 19628@00 | 19628 |
| 12345.1 | 12345 |
| 12345.2 | 12345 |

I can get the "@00" removed but I can not get the decimals removed to get a single OrderNo when I have a decimal included. (They use the decimal for sub Jobs)

```
SELECT 
 ORDERNUMBER, 
 Case 
 when regexp_contains(ORDERNUMBER, "@") then regexp_extract(ORDERNUMBER,"(.*)@" ) 
 when regexp_contains(ORDERNUMBER, ".") then regexp_extract(ORDERNUMBER,"(.*)." )
 else ORDERNUMBER
 end as Outcome
 FROM `JOBHEADER`
```

I tried escaping the "." with \ and / but I have no idea how to find it using regexp

Comment: I would honestly look at normalizing your first column's data. You shouldn't mix different data types or different data values within the same column, much less both of those things at once.

Comment: The OrderNo is a free text field so I can not change it :( 
I have tried to get the Users to keep to a standard but they don't always follow instructions.

Comment: Surely there's some form of input validation you can do for whatever is submitting those orders? If not, explain more as to why.

Comment: Once I have removed the Decimal - I will group the order numbers together that have the same number. That should not be an issue to do but thought I will add this information so as to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: Sorry the Base DB is coming from a JobCosting system, we extract the raw tables and upload it to BigQuery to run our Dashboards  - I can not really change the source data at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select regexp_extract(OrderNo, r'[^@\.]+') as OrderNo
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: So simple - I am was trying to hard and made it more difficult than needed. 

Thank you so much

Comment: Sure. Consider also voting up the answer if it helped :o)